# Cross-referencing charts (e.g. munin) with log files

Tags: monitoring, logging, munin, logstash

Is there a charting package like Munin (or an addon for it) that will let me click on a graph period and then see all the logs on that box for that period? e.g. if I see a huge spike in disk I/O 12 hours ago I'd like to be able to instantly "zoom in" to all log files in /var/log (plus any custom logs like web application logs, etc.) for that box, then one-by-one turn off irrelevant logfiles with a checkbox or something, until I see the issue.

I'm thinking some kind of Munin/Logstash mashup.

Right now, I just open a new tab to logstash and run a query which works OK. But this happens often enough for me that I suspect there might be a better way out there I just don't know about yet.

Comment: This would be amazing. Can we offer a bounty for a solution?